# SQL Server Trigger switching Insert,Delete,Update

Tags: sql-server, triggers, dml

Hello is possible to switch between DML commands/operations (Insert,Delete,Update) on Trigger Body?, I try to snippet some T-SQL for understand me better :

```
CREATE TRIGGER DML_ON_TABLEA
   ON  TABLEA
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CASE 
    WHEN (INSERT) THEN
        -- INSERT ON AUX TABLEB 
    WHEN (DELETE) THEN
        -- DELETE ON AUX TABLEB 
    ELSE --OR WHEN (UPDATE) THEN
        -- UPDATE ON AUX TABLEB 
    END
END
GO
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I will show you a simple way to check this in SQL Server 2000 or 2005 (you forgot to mention which version you are using), but in general I agree with Remus that you should break these up into separate triggers:

```
DECLARE @i INT, @d INT;
SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM inserted;
SELECT @d = COUNT(*) FROM deleted;
IF @i + @d > 0
BEGIN
    IF @i > 0 AND @d = 0
    BEGIN
        -- logic for insert
    END

    IF @i > 0 AND @d > 0
    BEGIN
        -- logic for update
    END

    IF @i = 0 AND @d > 0
    BEGIN
        -- logic for delete
    END
END
```

Note that this may not be perfectly forward-compatible due to the complexity `MERGE` introduces in SQL Server 2008. See this Connect item for more information:

- [MERGE can cause a trigger to fire multiple times](https://web.archive.org/web/20131019021104/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/SQLServer/feedback/details/321930/merge-can-cause-a-trigger-to-fire-multiple-times)

So if you are planning to use SQL Server 2008 and `MERGE` in the future, then this is even more reason to split the trigger up into a trigger for each type of DML operation.

(And if you want more reasons to avoid `MERGE`, [read this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/merge).)

Comment: +1 for "more reason to split the trigger up".  That really saved a lot of time and just 'made-sense' - why bother with all the crap to figure out what needs to be done, when separate triggers gets the job done just as well.  Thanks @Aaron.

Comment: This is the link to the Microsoft Connect (which is retired now) item Aaron mentioned: http://connect.microsoft.com:80/SQLServer/feedback/details/321930/merge-can-cause-a-trigger-to-fire-multiple-times

Comment: @MarkVarnas I updated the URL. You have to go through the WayBack machine now.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`inserted` and `deleted` tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) to see what changes were made to the table.

For an UPDATE, the `deleted` table contains the old version of the row, and `inserted` the new version.

DELETE and INSERT use their own table as you would expect.

Answer (score 6):

You can have three separate triggers, one for INSERT one for UPDATE one for DELETE. Since each trigger is different, there is no need for switch logic.

Answer (score 2):

I think the general way to do this is to create a trigger for each action, like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_ON_TABLEA   
ON  TABLEA   
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN    
SET NOCOUNT ON;    
-- INSERT ON AUX TABLEB
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DELETE_ON_TABLEA   
ON  TABLEA   
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN    
SET NOCOUNT ON;    
-- DELETE ON AUX TABLEB
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one trigger for all commands/operations by use union join;

```
CREATE TRIGGER DML_ON_TABLEA
 ON  TABLEA
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
   --logic for insert
    insert into Backup_table (columns_name) select columns_name from inserted i
    --logic for delete
   UNION ALL
    insert into Backup_table (columns_name) select columns_name from deleted d
END
GO
```

--note update command  like inserted command but have another command deleted