# SQL Server trigger - SET variable = column.value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a trigger which is operating on table `component` and logging `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT` operation to the table `component_history`

```
CREATE TRIGGER component_hist
ON component
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

DECLARE
   @tr_action varchar(8),
   @tr_id_compoment int,
   @tr_name varchar(max),
   @tr_value int

IF COLUMNS_UPDATED() <> 0 -- delete or update?
BEGIN     
  SET @tr_action = 'UPDATE'
ELSE -- delete     
BEGIN
  SET @tr_action = 'DELETE'
END

INSERT INTO component_history VALUES (@tr_id_component, @tr_name, @tr_value, @tr_action);
```

How can I send information from columns (`id, name, value`) from table `component` into `component_history`?

I've tried:

```
SET 
@tr_id_component = component.id,
@tr_name = component.name,
@tr_value = component.value
```

but it reports:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure component_hist, Line 22
>   The multi-part identifier "component.id" could not be bound.

Comment: Some element of anwser to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751715/sql-server-trigger-switching-insert-delete-update

Comment: Assuming at least one insert has already been successfully processed (so rows exist in the table), `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM component)` will always be true. And triggers fire once per statement, not once per row, so thinking of putting values into variables is always wrong-headed.

Comment: It's a second thing, it was a construction for ORACLE, but MSSQL doesn't support BEFORE statement, so I'm using AFTER only for now (I don't know how to solve BEFORE) :((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should suffice:

```
CREATE TRIGGER component_hist
ON component
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

INSERT INTO component_history /* I'd prefer to see a column list here */
select id,name,value,CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * from deleted) THEN 'UPDATE' ELSE 'INSERT' END
from inserted
UNION ALL
select id,name,value,'DELETE'
from deleted
where not exists(select * from inserted)
```

A *small* optimization (if you have lots of **large** updates) would be to move the `EXISTS (select * from deleted)` evaluation out of the `SELECT` (since it will currently be assessed once per row).

Note, also, that in the `UPDATE` case, we're just storing the new values, not the old values.

---

The [`inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) are special - they contain the rows that were affected by the statement that caused the trigger to fire. The `inserted` table contains any new rows, and the `deleted` table contains any old rows. This leads to the logic that during an `insert`, `deleted` will be empty (no old rows were affected by the insert). And during a `delete`, `inserted` will be empty (no new rows have been created). During an `update`, both tables are populated.

This is why the top part of the `select` applies to both `insert` and `update` operations, because we're using the `inserted` table. But we check whether there are any rows in `deleted`, to distinguish the two operations. In the bottom `select` (below the `union all`), we query the `deleted` table - but we use the `where` clause to prevent any rows being returned if this is actually an `update` operation.

Comment: Damien, could you explain me how it works a little bit? It works, but i don't know how...

Comment: @gaffcz - I've added some explanation, guessing you wanted info on `inserted` and `deleted`. If not, can you say which bit(s) are not clear to you?