# What is the best way to figure out if an UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT occur for a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to create a single trigger in MS SQL for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE but I want to be able to simple extract the data without 3 IF statements

I want to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @PK  int

SELECT @PK = COALESCE(i.PK, d.PK)
FROM inserted i, deleted d
```

This did not work but would like to know if I can do it in one query.

What are some alternatives?

Comment: Instead of the comma join, have you tried SELECT @PK = COALESCE(i.PK, d.PK)
FROM inserted i full outer join deleted d on i.PK = d.PK?

Comment: full outer join works.. thanks. that was what I was going to try next:0)

Comment: Extract the data to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a FULL OUTER JOIN

```
DECLARE @DataIWanted as varchar(255)

SELECT @DataIWanted = COALESCE(i.TheData,d.TheData)
FROM inserted i
   FULL OUTER JOIN deleted d on d.PK=i.PK
```

The query above will be from the deleted table or the inserted/updated table. With the assumption that TheData is defined as NON NULL in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the switch logic found here: [SQL Server Trigger switching Insert,Delete,Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751715/sql-server-trigger-switching-insert-delete-update)

Or you can create 3 different triggers.

Those are you options.